# CardIO conflicts with OpenCV framework

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, conflict, card.io, cardio

I thoroughly enjoy using Card.IO but in order for me to use it, it would have to be decoupled from it's OpenCV .a files, and instead link to the OpenCV framework. Most people have moved on from OpenCV2 to OpenCV3, and this library is stuck in the past. There appears to be no way to work around this, since your dependency is baked into your .a file. (calling creators of Card IO)

Has anyone else been able to work around this? Or is this library junk now if you use OpenCV?

Thanks,
Kevin